# DevExpress and C#

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

How to do gridcontrol search from row zero, for example in cell zero write the code of the product and when pressing tab it loads the description and other data and I want to know in which event I can do that search, I am working in C# and SQL Server, I want to do the search as I show it in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Handle the gridView1_CellValueChanged event.

Something like this:

```
private void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Column.Name)
   {
      case "NAME_OF_PRODUCT_COL":
       {
           var itemCode = e.Value.ToString();
           //Lookup the description in the lookup table
           string description = ""; //Replace with lookup value
           gridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, colDescription, description); //Replace colDescription with the correct name for the description column
          break;
       }
     }
}
```